# How to keep cookie stored after logging out of Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

Based on Codex.Wordpress, "There are cookies for logged in users and for commenters." I tested this by showing all the stored cookies, and a lot were stored while logged in, but when i refreshed the page after logging out, all cookie values were gone.

Is there a way for me to store a cookie value after logging out? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? The cookies are properly related to being logged in, why would you want to store them? I can only imagine that it would cause issues or prevent you from logging out all together.

Comment: if you want to store cookies of your own you can set it on login hook it will not be deleted by wordpress on logout. otherwise keeping cookies will keep you from logging out.